# VBA method 'range of object' _Worksheet failed Shapes.Range(Array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to move shapes on the 2nd sheet based on the values of the 1st sheet. I keep getting an error with the line....Shapes.Range(Array(.... below is the code.

```
Sub graphics_mover()
' graphics_mover Macro

Dim SWL_row As Double, PWL_row As Double
Dim rng As Variant, i As Integer, colNum As Integer, Data As Worksheet, Pict As Worksheet
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'Set Pict = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set Pict = Workbooks("Well Pictographs2.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
i = 1
For i = 1 To 27
    SWL_row = Data.Cells(2, i + 1).Value
    SWL_row = Int(SWL_row / 50 + 1)
    Pict.Shapes.Range(Array("Isosceles Triangle " & i)).Select
    Selection.Top = SWL_row * 15 + 4

    PWL_row = Data.Cells(3, i + 1).Value
    PWL_row = Int(PWL_row / 50 + 1)
    Pict.Shapes.Range(Array("Freeform " & i)).Select
    Selection.Top = PWL_row * 15 + 1
    i = i + 1
Next i
    '--------------------------
End Sub
```

the line that is causing the error is:

```
    Pict.Shapes.Range(Array("Freeform " & i)).Select
```

I appreciate any solutions.

Comment: If `Pict.Shapes.Range(Array("Isosceles Triangle " & i)).Select` works and `Pict.Shapes.Range(Array("Freeform " & i)).Select` doesn't then the only difference can be that not all the names `Freeform 1` through `Freeform 27` exist.  Otherwise why would the other line work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious as to what the value of *i* is when you crash. The code is largely the same as a recorded macro but the syntax is correct if the named shape(s) exist.

First run this small snippet to output all of the shapes' names to the VBE's Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

```
Sub List_Shapes()
    Dim i As Long
    With Workbooks("Well Pictographs2.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
        For i = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            Debug.Print .Shapes(i).Name
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

When you are in the VBE, tap Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window and check the output. Make sure you have *Isosceles Triangle 1* through *Isosceles Triangle 27* (inclusive).

Next run through this modification of your macro.

```
Sub graphics_mover()
    Dim SWL_row As Double, PWL_row As Double
    Dim rng As Variant, i As Integer, colNum As Integer, Data As Worksheet, Pict As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With Workbooks("Well Pictographs2.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
        For i = 1 To 27
            SWL_row = Data.Cells(2, i + 1).Value
            SWL_row = Int(SWL_row / 50 + 1)
            If Not .Shapes("Isosceles Triangle " & i) Is Nothing Then
                .Shapes("Isosceles Triangle " & i).Top = SWL_row * 15 + 4
                Debug.Print "moved " & .Shapes("Isosceles Triangle " & i).Name
            End If

            PWL_row = Data.Cells(3, i + 1).Value
            PWL_row = Int(PWL_row / 50 + 1)
            If Not .Shapes("Freeform " & i) Is Nothing Then
                .Shapes("Freeform " & i).Top = PWL_row * 15 + 1
                Debug.Print "moved " & .Shapes("Freeform " & i).Name
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not a big fan of using `On Error Resume Next` but you are dealing with an object that is avoiding detection. The VBE's Immediate window will report the shapes that it could move.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the value of i would be an odd number. The code adds an extra i = i + 1 to the loop ; so there could not be "Freeform 2" or "Freeform 4" : thus, shapes by those names (with even number) would not exist, which would trigger the error.

I was answering the question : "I'm curious as to what the value of i is when you crash" (from user4039065).
It is clear that the value of i would be uneven. Starting with 1, it adds 1 twice (i = i + 1 and Next i) 14 times.
The original code reads :

```
i = 1
For i = 1 To 27
    'move various items
    i = i + 1
Next i
```

Any object indexed by i will have an odd number in its name :
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27.
In case of doubt, try this :

```
Sub CheckLoop()
    Dim i As Integer, s As String

    i = 1
    For i = 1 To 27
        s = s & i & " "
        i = i + 1
    Next i
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

I should have said that this *might* trigger the error.
(I.E. invoking shapes by those names (with even number like "Freeform 2" or "Freeform 4"), which would not exist, could trigger an error, if not *the* error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).